# JPA id generation generic strategy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i have an application that uses JPA-Hibernate correctly with MySQL. In this case, i'm using for the id generation in the entities an auto strategy.
In the other hand, i have other application that uses Oracle, and i'm using a sequence strategy for this.
The point is that i want to know if it's possible to use a "generic" strategy for Oracle/MySQL/Sql Server, and make my applications more portable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy way to have portable solution is to use [TableGenerator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/TableGenerator.html). Values are managed in database table and retrieved and inceremented with SQL queries, so no database vendor specific constructs are used.

Answer (score 0):

The generic strategies that don't rely on particular DB features require additional tables for ID generation. Such strategies: `hilo`, `enhanced-table`. Also you can use strategies based on UUID generation such as `uuid.hex`, `uuid`, `uuid2`. Other strategies would use different DB-specific features and thus might differ in behavior. For instance `native` works differently for MySQL and Postgres, in MySQL (generators) you have insert right when you save an object, in Postgres (sequences) you'll get insert only on regular flushes. You might want to take a look at sources of `DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory` to see all the possible strategies and explore their algorithms and docs.

Note, that generally it's a bad idea to make 2 or more heterogeneous apps working with the same DB, especially if they all are writing to the database. Your DB will be very hard to maintain and refactor.

Comment: I don't think that this is about making two apps use the same database. As far as I understand OP's question he wants portability.